# Is it possible to add up the accuracy rates of 2 separate predictors?

Tags: probability, soft-question

Weather channel 1 has a 65% accuracy rate of predicting tomorrows weather

Weather channel 2 has a 59% accuracy rate of predicting tomorrows weather

---

Is it somehow possible to take into account their respective accuracy rates and predictions to somehow make a more accurate predictor?

What would the rates be if the both channels had the same prediction?

What would the rates be if the both channels had different predictions?

---

What specific topics/subjects cover this particular problem (that of combining different predictors)?

- `accuracy_rate` will be defined in this question to avoid confusion as the

  (# of correct predictions / # of total predictions) the channel has made

Comment: What's an accuracy rate? Are you modelling weather by a finite number of states so that it makes sense to ask whether a prediction was correct?

Comment: @Alan Try asking on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there some structure to the prediction space? E.g., could an average of the predictions be formed? Because if there isn't, if it's just an unstructured set of possible predictions (as your definition of the accuracy rate seems to suggest), then the combined predictor can't do any better than just say what the better of the two predictors says.

Comment: @joriki This is an old question, but when I asked it, I was mainly searching for lossless methods to obtain a predictor by merging a number of older predictors. I was looking for a straightforward way to enhance results by combining a variety of publicly available models from literature.

Comment: @AlanSTACK: I don't see how that answers my question :-)

Comment: @joriki In that case, I suppose the answer is that I don't have a clue. It's been years now and what I ended up doing was slap a neural network on top of both predictors and moving on with life. Cheers.

Comment: @AlanSTACK: OK, then I have a new question :-) Why did you add "separate" in the title after all those years? That doesn't really add to the meaning or clarity of the title. I was assuming that you wanted to bump the question because it hadn't been answered, but if you've moved on, why make a trivial change?

Comment: @joriki I spent the last 30 minutes revising old questions and fixing grammar because having better-written posts boosted my intellectual self-esteem and because I didn't want to start my weekend list of chores yet. Also, I was unaware that editing posts bumped them.